# How to use Composer packages in a PyroCMS module?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, composer-php, pyrocms

I wonder what is the best way (or at least a good one) to import some Composer libraries into a PyroCMS app, and especially in a module.

I know Phil Sturgeon already proposed a method for CodeIgniter, and PyroCMS is built on top of CodeIgniter. http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter

But PyroCMS is dropping CI for Laravel, plus PyroCMS brings an extra layer called *modules*.

I mean, *modules should be self-contained*, everything in a single folder. That's why I did not follow Phil Sturgeon's article.

This is an example of how I am doing currently:

```
my_module/
  controllers/
  models/
  views/
  libraries/
    Lib1.php
    Lib2.php
    vendor/
    composer.json
    ...
  ...
```

When I need to load some Composer package, I add this in my controller:

```
require_once __DIR__'../libraries/vendor/autoload.php';
```

In most cases, that would work fine.

But, I had a problem with one particular package, `Guzzle`. It could not find the CAcert files or something... Finally, importing Guzzle with a `phar` file saved me.

But I'd prefer to only use Composer if possible. So maybe I am wrong in the way I load the packages. Maybe Composer should not be placed here?

Keep in mind that a module should be able to install itself.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you move to 2.3 release? I'm working with it and it uses composer to handle packages, that's the best. I tried in 2.2.x without success and I leave it to move to 2.3/dev. Try it!!

Comment: My question was precisely for PyroCMS 2.2. ^^ Plus, 2.3 has been in development for a while now, and it seems not to be changing soon. It is for using in a production environment. FOr the moment, I've changed nothing, I still do how I said in my post.